# ¿Puede alguien solucionar este error de valor nulo, soy nuevo en java?

Tags: java, netbeans, consola

Hola estoy empezando en java, y me apareció este error, alguien puede decirme como quedaría
arreglado. Según he leído es por asignar un valor nulo a la variable, pero no sé resolverlo.[image: Os dejo una captura]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, por favor agrega el còdigo y el mensaje de error como texto ya que como imagen no todos los miembros de la comunidad lo podemos ver. Te invitamos a revisar tambièn [ask] y [tour], saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: el error no esta en esa parte del codigo, tiene que ver con return

Answer (score 0):

el NullPointerException ocurre cuando se hace uso de una variable que referencia a un objeto pero que el contenido de la variable es null, de modo que al ser null la llamada al método no es posible, porque "no existe", o sea no hay nada.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int sueldoSemanal;
        int horasTrabajadas;
        Scanner leerDato= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca numero de "
                + "horas trabajadas durante la semana ");
        horasTrabajadas= leerDato.nextInt();
        if (horasTrabajadas<=40) sueldoSemanal= 8*horasTrabajadas;
        else sueldoSemanal=(40*8)+((horasTrabajadas-40)*12);
        
        System.out.println("Sueldo semanal: $"+sueldoSemanal);
    }
```

El Scanner es una manera mas sencilla (para mi) de leer datos ingresados por teclado. Espero te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Julian.